# jquery how to call a function on document ready

Tags: jquery

Hi could someone help me out with this jQuery? I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    window.refresh = function () { setorganisationddl; }

    var setorganisationddl = function () {
        if ($("#Invoice_AreaId option:selected").val() == "") {
            $("#Invoice_OrganisationId > option").remove();
            $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").append($("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>"));
            $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $.get('/Invoice/GetOrganisationSelectList/' + $("#Invoice_AreaId option:selected").val(), function (response) {
                $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").removeAttr("disabled");

                var organisations = $.parseJSON(response);

                var ddlOrganisations = $("#Invoice_OrganisationId");

                $("#Invoice_OrganisationId > option").remove();

                for (i = 0; i < organisations.length; i++) {

                    if (organisations[i].Value == $("#Invoice_OrganisationId option:selected").val()) {
                        ddlOrganisations.append($("<option selected='selected' />").val(organisations[i].Value).text(organisations[i].Text));
                    }
                    else {
                        ddlOrganisations.append($("<option />").val(organisations[i].Value).text(organisations[i].Text));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $("#Invoice_AreaId").change(setorganisationddl);
});
```

So I have setorganisationddl being called when ddl with id Invoice_AreaId is changed. Great. However I also want it called when the page loaded.

As you can see I tried:

```
window.refresh = function () { setorganisationddl; }
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to re-arrange your code a bit.

put a call to `setorganisationddl` in your document ready,  and in the `.change` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    setorganisationddl();



    $("#Invoice_AreaId").change(function(){
         setorganisationddl();
    });
});

function setorganisationddl() {
    if ($("#Invoice_AreaId option:selected").val() == "") {
        $("#Invoice_OrganisationId > option").remove();
        $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").append($("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>"));
        $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $.get('/Invoice/GetOrganisationSelectList/' + $("#Invoice_AreaId option:selected").val(), function (response) {
            $("#Invoice_OrganisationId").removeAttr("disabled");

            var organisations = $.parseJSON(response);

            var ddlOrganisations = $("#Invoice_OrganisationId");

            $("#Invoice_OrganisationId > option").remove();

            for (i = 0; i < organisations.length; i++) {

                if (organisations[i].Value == $("#Invoice_OrganisationId option:selected").val()) {
                    ddlOrganisations.append($("<option selected='selected' />").val(organisations[i].Value).text(organisations[i].Text));
                }
                else {
                    ddlOrganisations.append($("<option />").val(organisations[i].Value).text(organisations[i].Text));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call it in your `.ready()` handler:

```
var setorganisationddl = function () {
    ...
}
setorganisationddl();
```

If you really want it to be called when the page is fully loaded, and not just when it is ready, you'll need to define the function outside of any `ready` handler.

```
function setorganisationddl () {
    ...
}
$(window).load(setorganisationddl);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Invoice_AreaId").change(setorganisationddl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do -

```
$("#Invoice_AreaId").change(setorganisationddl).change();
```

at the bottom of your code, and remove the `window.refresh` call. That should bind the function then trigger the 'change' event.